# How to duplicate an SQLAlchemy-mapped object the correct way?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to duplicate (copy) an object mapped by SQLAlchemy. It should only copy the data created by me, not all the underliying stuff. It shouldn't copy the primary keys or unique values.

This is usefull when creating new data entries which differ only a little from the last one. So the user doesn't have to enter all data again.

An **important requirement** is that this need to work when the column name in the table (e.g. `name`) and the memeber name (e.g. `_name`) in the python class are not the same.

This (simplified) code work for all declarative_base() derived classes BUT ONLY when the col-name and the member-name are the same.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

def DuplicateObject(oldObj):
    mapper = sa.inspect(type(oldObj))
    newObj = type(oldObj)()

    for col in mapper.columns:
        # no PrimaryKey not Unique
        if not col.primary_key and not col.unique:
            setattr(newObj, col.key, getattr(oldObj, col.key))

    return newObj
```

`col.key` is the name of the column in the table. When the member name in the python class is different this wouldn't work. I don't know how SQLAlchemy connect the column-name with the member-name. How does SQLA know this connection? How can I take care of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sqlalchemy as sqa

def duplicate_object(old_obj):
    # SQLAlchemy related data class?
    if not isinstance(old_obj, _Base):
        raise TypeError('The given parameter with type {} is not '
                        'mapped by SQLAlchemy.'.format(type(old_obj)))

    mapper = sa.inspect(type(old_obj))
    new_obj = type(old_obj)()

    for name, col in mapper.columns.items():
        # no PrimaryKey not Unique
        if not col.primary_key and not col.unique:
            setattr(new_obj, name, getattr(old_obj, name))

    return new_obj
```

It looks like that this work. Even when the members have begin with double underlines (`__name`).

But someone on the [SQLA-mailinglist](https://groups.google.com/forum/?_escaped_fragment_=forum/sqlalchemy#!forum/sqlalchemy) [mentioned](https://groups.google.com/forum/?_escaped_fragment_=msg/sqlalchemy/bIdinJmRCjg/vkRBxqfs-tsJ#!msg/sqlalchemy/bIdinJmRCjg/vkRBxqfs-tsJ)

> It’s not a generalized solution for the whole world, though. It doesn’t take into account columns that are part of unique Index objects or columns that are mentioned in standalone UniqueConstraint objects.

But because the SQLA-docu is (for me!) quite hard to read and understand I am not really sure what happen in that code - especially in the `for`-construct. What is behind `items()` and why are there two parameters (`name`, `col`)?

Comment: The last question is less of an SQLAlchemy question but more a quite basic Python question.  `mapper.columns` is a mapping (`dict` or `dict` -like) and `items()` returns an iterable with all key/value pairs as tuples.  Between `for` and `in` you can write anything that would be legal on the left hand side of an assignment. This includes multiple names for tuple/sequence unpacking.